# how to use isdigit() method in side function with if

Tags: python

how cani use isdigit method Like that `if self.month.isdigit():`

ineed to know if my input is Digit or Not

```
class myclass():
def __init__(self,year,month,day):
    self.mah = ['none','farvardin','ordibehesht','khordad','tir','mordad','shahrivar','mehr','aban','azar','dey','bahman','esfand']
    self.daylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
    self.year = year
    self.month = month
    self.day = day
def myfunc(self):
    if self.month.isdigit(): # problem is (isdigit) not working



p1= input("Please enter date:")
year,month,day = p1.split('-')
p2 = myclass(year,month,day)
p2.myfunc()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146. We can only help you with problems that you actually explain; "it's not working" isn't sufficient. How do you run the code (what do you type as the date)? What is supposed to happen when you run the code? What happens instead, and how is that different? Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and make sure your code is properly formatted exactly as you have it - indentation is crucial in Python.

Comment: "ineed to know if my input is String or int" Input gives a *string*. Splitting a string gives a list *of strings*. Assigning a list of strings to separate variables makes them *strings*. A string like `"789"` **is not** an integer. It is still a **string**.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sry i want to know its Digit or Not

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it takes like 2021-05-10   But maybe you insert  2021-april-10 insted

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just need to fix this condition of the code, not the whole program

Comment: Don't use `range` name for your class, that is a builtin method, Use `Range` at minima

Comment: @azro thx i will edit but its not my problem anyway

Comment: Also share an example for which it isn't working

Comment: " I just need to fix this condition of the code, not the whole program " That's fine, and I understand that. You still need to read the links I gave you and fix your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tiago as per my understanding I have updated your code. As you are taking input from stdin inputs p1 will be a string object only but if p1 doesn't have any "-" in it then the code will generate unpack error. For example, if you pass **20211114**.

```
Please enter date: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jdoodle.py", line 19, in <module>
    year,month,day = p1.split('-')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

- I have changed your class name from **range** to
  **CustomRange**
- Plus for **daylist** variable I used list comprehension.

  ```
   class CustomRange():
   def __init__(self,year,month,day):
       self.daylist = [i for i in range(1,32)]
       self.year = year
       self.month = month
       self.day = day
       self.mah = ['none','farvardin','ordibehesht','khordad','tir','mordad','shahrivar','mehr','aban','azar','dey','bahman','esfand']
   def myfunc(self):
       if self.month.isdigit(): # problem is (isdigit) not working
           print(self.month, "is number")
           return True
       else:
           print(self.month, "is not number")
           return False

   p1= input("Please enter date: ")
   year,month,day = p1.split('-')
   p2 = CustomRange(year,month,day)
   p2.myfunc()
  ```

Comment: Please read [answer] and don't guess at the problem - it is OP's responsibility to explain what "not working" means, not your responsibility to decide what it might mean and answer on that basis.